# Gradient Decent using SGDRegressor algorithm of scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gradient-descent

I am implementing Gradient Decent using SGDRegressor algorithm of scikit-learn on my rental dataset to predict rent on the basis of the area but getting weird coefficients and intercept, and therefore, weird predictions for rent.

---

Rental Dataset : rentals.csv (Firnished column

```
area,bedrooms,furnished,cost
650,2,1,33000
750,3,0,55000
247,1,0,10500
1256,4,0,65000
900,3,0,37000
900,3,0,50000
550,2,0,30000
1700,4,0,72000
1300,4,0,45000
1600,4,2,57000
475,2,1,30000
800,3,0,45000
350,2,0,15000
247,1,0,11500
247,1,0,16500
247,1,0,15000
330,2,0,16000
450,2,2,25000
325,1,0,13500
1650,4,0,90000
650,2,0,31000
1650,4,0,65000
900,3,0,40000
635,2,0,30000
475,2,2,28000
1120,3,0,45000
1000,3,0,38000
900,3,2,50000
610,3,0,28000
400,2,0,17000
```

Python Code with alpha value =  .000001 and max_iter=1000

```
import pandas
full_data = pandas.read_csv ("./rentals.csv")
rentals = pandas.DataFrame ({'area':full_data.area,'cost':full_data.cost})

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, test = train_test_split (rentals, test_size=0.2, random_state=11)

trainX = pandas.DataFrame ({'area': train['area']})
trainY = pandas.DataFrame ({'cost': train['cost']})
testX = pandas.DataFrame ({'area': test['area']})
testY = pandas.DataFrame ({'cost': test['cost']})

from sklearn.linear_model import SGDRegressor
reg = SGDRegressor(max_iter=1000, alpha=.000001, tol=.0001)

reg.fit (trainX, trainY)

from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, r2_score

print ('Coefficients: \n', reg.coef_)
print ('Intercept: \n', reg.intercept_)

yhat = reg.predict (testX)

print ('Mean squared error: \n', mean_squared_error (testY, yhat))
print ('Variance score: \n', r2_score (testY, yhat))

print('yhat :: ',yhat)
```

OUTPUT

```
Coefficients:
 [-1.77569698e+12]
Intercept:
 [2.20231032e+10]
Mean squared error:
 2.7699546187784015e+30
Variance score:
 -1.1843036374824519e+22
yhat ::  [-4.38575131e+14 -2.30838405e+15 -9.76611316e+14 -1.77567496e+15
 -2.23025338e+15 -1.42053556e+15]
```

When Alpha = .00000001

```
reg = SGDRegressor(max_iter=1000, alpha=.00000001, tol=.0001)
```

OUTPUT

```
Coefficients:
 [-1.35590231e+12]
Intercept:
 [-9.70811558e+10]
Mean squared error:
 1.6153367348228915e+30
Variance score:
 -6.906427844848468e+21
yhat ::  [-3.35004951e+14 -1.76277008e+15 -7.45843351e+14 -1.35599939e+15
 -1.70311038e+15 -1.08481893e+15]
```

I have tried all the values till alpha = .00000000001

```
reg = SGDRegressor(max_iter=1000, alpha=.00000000001, tol=.0001)
```

OUTPUT

```
Coefficients:
 [1.81827102e+12]
Intercept:
 [8.5060188e+09]
Mean squared error:
 2.9044685546452095e+30
Variance score:
 -1.2418155340525837e+22
yhat ::  [4.49121448e+14 2.36376083e+15 1.00005757e+15 1.81827952e+15
 2.28375691e+15 1.45462532e+15]
```

Please suggest what is incorrect in my code ? Why I am getting incorrect values ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for posting a short, complete, and working code example as well as the data. Ideally, you should make the data part of the code to simplify the copy&paste process for people trying to help. Also, the outputs for different alphas are a bit much. It would have been enough to post one representative output and state that smaller alphas do not make a difference (why would they, anyway?).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing obviously wrong with the code. Interestingly, if we replace `SGDRegressor` with simple `LinearRegression` the results look good (coef = ~40, r2score = ~0.7). There must be something about the data that stochastic gradient does not like.

What I *believe* is happening is that due to the large scale of the data the gradient gets too large and the algorithm diverges.

We can verify this by setting a low learning rate, forcing the algorithm to take small steps, even if the gradient is high:

```
reg = SGDRegressor(max_iter=1000, alpha=.000001, tol=.0001, learning_rate='constant', eta0=1e-7)

# Coefficients: [46.75739932]
# Intercept: [0.11470854]
# Mean squared error: 75520077.45401965
# Variance score: 0.6771113077975406
```

This looks better, but it may not be an ideal solution because with large data sets training can take ages if the learning rate is low. Instead, let's do something about the scale of the data:

```
mu_x = trainX.mean().values
mu_y = trainY.mean().values
scale_x = trainX.std().values
scale_y = trainY.std().values

trainX = (trainX - mu_x) / scale_x
trainY = (trainY - mu_y) / scale_y

reg = SGDRegressor(max_iter=1000, alpha=.000001, tol=.0001)

reg.fit(trainX, trainY)

yhat = reg.predict((testX - mu_x) / scale_x) * scale_y + mu_y

# Coefficients: [0.89319654]
# Intercept: [0.00064678]
# Mean squared error: 59575772.471740596
# Variance score: 0.7452817328999215
```

Centering and rescaling the data helps a lot. There is also the scikit-learn [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) but I like to show the manual approach to illustrate what's going on.